# All LGAs for Australia in KML or KMZ format

Tags: kml, kmz, australia

Can somebody please show me where to find a KML or KMZ file that includes the digital boundaries for all Local Government Areas in Australia?

Comment: For Queensland you could try the [**Queensland Spatial Portal**](http://www.information.qld.gov.au/).

Answer (score 2):

From the [Australian Bureau of Statistics](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/mf/1259.0.30.001):

> The product includes boundaries of Local Government Areas, Statistical
>   Local Areas, Statistical Divisions, Statistical Subdivisions, States,
>   Statistical Districts, Major Statistical Regions, Statistical Regions
>   and Statistical Region Sectors, current at 1 July 2011. The digital
>   boundaries are available only at one level of detail. These boundaries
>   are intended for import and display in GIS and desktop mapping
>   packages and, because of the high level of detail, they are not
>   suitable for use in 'low-end' mapping packages such as those included
>   in Excel.

It's in .shp, .mid, and .mif

[Here](http://spatialnews.geocomm.com/articles/overviewofkmlconversionprograms/) is an explanation of some of the ways to convert from a shapefile to KML. And [here](https://developers.google.com/kml/articles/vector) is a breakdown of how to use GDAL to convert as well.

Comment: Thanks Paul - unfortunately I am only after a KML or KMZ file as I don't have GIS or other mapping software.

Comment: There are various free and open source methods out there to convert from shapefiles to KML. See my links at the bottom.